# Opening finder instances extremely slow in browsers and quicksilver since 10.6.7 update

Tags: macos, finder

Since the update OSX to 10.6.7 opening finder windows (such as when you want to save an image in a browser) takes between 5-10 seconds and then an additional 1-3 seconds to show places in the finder window.

I have tried installing [Onyx](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11582/onyx) and rebuilding the links in LaunchServices, and this solved the problem but after a day or so the problem returned.

There most be some kind of permanent solution to this so I don't have to format and reinstall.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you update to 10.6.7 using the Software Update utility? Or did you use the [Update Combo](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1361)?

It's not unheard of for the Software Update utility to muck things up. The advantage of using the Update Combo is that it rewrites everything, as opposed to doing a 'delta' upgrade.

It should be noted that the Update Combo package is now weighing in at over 1 GB.

You won't do any harm, and you may fix things, by running the Update Combo linked to above.

Comment: @boehj: You are right, I haven't faced a similar issue after 10.6.7 update. @Ancide: Please update your system using Update Combo.

Comment: Yep, I would also recommend the combo. +1

Comment: No worries, I hope it works. :)

Comment: I can confirm this fixed the problem, so thank you very very much!

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: But the problem returned today. I have filed a bug report to Apple and will be formatting my computer next week :/

Comment: @Ancide - What a bummer. Sorry to hear it didn't work out as planned.